# Android notification after an application was closed

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-browser

I've been looking around and I can't find any way to get a notification when an application was closed by the user in Android. I know, you'll say onPause() or onStop(), but what if I can't touch the Android application? This is what I need: If the user closes the Browser application, I want to be notified about that event. Is there any way to do this in Android without actually modifying the Browser app?

Comment: This would be a huge security hole.

Comment: I don't know if this will be a security hole. I know about a valid scenario for this (SIM ToolKit, Browser Termination event). There should be a way to attach to a process to check if it's running, when it exits and the exit code.

Comment: Oh sure there are plenty of ways to trap exit codes from apps. However you'd need a controlling process to see that, and it'd need to be running in OS space. So what you want is probably perfectly doable with some hacks on a rooted phone. But it's definitely not supported by the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Hate the be the bearer of bad news  but there is really no way to do this unless you write something by hand.  One way would be to use something like a task manager and sniff all the running applications and then see if your browser is running.  Then if it is running send a message out when it closes.  There really is no easy way to do this as you want information on system root/level processes.